# word-wrap with cufon

Tags: css, fonts, cufon

this is css:

```
h3 {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  margin-bottom: 9px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

& then applying cufon as:

```
Cufon.replace('h3');
```

but text is still rendering in single line.
if I'm doing anything wrong here?

Comment: Are there any specific reason for you to use cufon? you can replace fonts with a custom @font-face (and then you don't have to use javascript). Here you can read a guide about it: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/ and then here you can convert your fonts: http://www.font2web.com/

Comment: @Chris:Thanks for your reply but unfortunately I've to go with Cufon only.

Comment: if you could provide a link it would be easier to test and debug, please specify if you got any!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cufon posseses a `separate` property which you can set to `'words', 'none' or 'characters'`.

Also, a common denominator of many problems I have encountered while working with Cufon is not specifying a `STRICT DOCTYPE` document header.

You can read more at: https://github.com/sorccu/cufon/wiki/API